# Expire create-react-app service worker cache from users browsers

Tags: create-react-app, service-worker, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

I had previously created a website for my band on `thescratch.ie` using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/keoghpe/react-scratch) and hosted this using S3 and Cloudfront. I recently replaced the react site using Shopify instead and `thescratch.ie` domain now points to Shopify.

For new users to the site, everything works fine but old users continue to see a broken cached version of the react website, not a Shopify site. I had assumed that the cache would eventually expire for these users, but it's been like this for a couple of months now.

Looking at the Chrome dev tools network panel I notice a couple of things:

- Almost everything is being served from cache - the index.html and main.js return a 200 and have a size of (service worker)
- Images return a 404
- The manifest.json returns a 404

I'm wondering if there's a way to expire the service worker cache? Is it possible to do this by hosting a new manifest.json file on Shopify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in a combination of CRA & Gatsby.
Found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-remove-serviceworker) Gatsby plugin which helped me.

The [underlying article](https://medium.com/@nekrtemplar/self-destroying-serviceworker-73d62921d717) maybe also can help you.

tl;dr in my understanding you need to place a `service-worker.js` in the root directory containing the code to unregister the old service worker.